# No hot water after installing shower: could this connection be the cause?

Tags: plumbing

After installing this new shower valve, the cold water is working fine, and the hot water is not. Cold should be on the right, hot on the left. The left connection did not have enough length of pipe, and thus you can see that between the elbow and the compression fitting, there's no bare pipe (there is pipe in there, but perhaps not enough).

My next plan is to detach this, and add some pipe. But before I do, is this a valid reason for the hot water not coming through?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. So, are the hot and cold inlets reversed? If so, then that could do it. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Could there be a hot water isolating valve that was turned off to do the work and not turned back on? Just to be sure.

Comment: Maybe a valve on the hot water tank?

Comment: that pipe being short would not cause hot water not to flow... if anything it would have caused that fitting not to seat right and you'd be leaking water there.

Comment: it makes no sense to expect plumbing pipes to be symmetrical

Comment: make sure the cartridge is positioned correctly before the handle is installed and that the handle rotate fully.

Comment: Some valves have small flow controls to balance them. A short pipe will not affect anything as jack said. You may have to remove your knob and possibly the trim to gain access to the adjusting valve , I have also seen these get plugged by a small amount of pfte tape that ended up inside the pipe, but if your other hot water works in the bath look for a adjusting valve, it may be closed.

Comment: Hot on the left and cold on the right when you are standing in front of it.  That picture appears to be the back, so the cold is what you have circled, or am I missing something?